# Error on C# script component of an SSIS package callled from an SQL Server agent Job

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a **C# script** that is being called from an **SSIS package**. This script compresses files in a folderA and saves the compressed file to folderB.

When I run this SSIS package(that calls the C# script) manually from **Microsoft Visual Studio,** it runs successfully. However, once I deploy this package to the **SSIS DB** of my database server and create an **SQL Server Agent Job** and run this job, the package calling the C# script fails.

When I try to check the **'All Executions' report** of the running SSIS project, I notice there is an error message saying, `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`

This error message is not really informative thus, I do not know why this error happens.

Any ideas on why this error occurs or help to further narrow down my investigation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do other C# scripts work OK or is this the first one you've tried? Did you run it in VS on the _SQL Server_ or on a different machine? Are you certain the SQL Agent user has all required access? Is the compression tool installed on the SQL Server? Please update your question with this further info. See here for one guess: Knowing this helps narrow down the problem. C# scripts need admin access to `c:\windows\temp` and you might not have this access (see here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mab/2008/11/06/custom-security-and-sql-job-with-ssis-script-task/).

Comment: 90% of SQL Agent problems are because the SQL Agent service account doesn't have access, or because the OP doesn't realise it's running it on a different computer (i.e. file paths and installed libraries are not valid)

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, thanks for your answer. Indeed, the problem was because the sql agent service account was not granted write permission to the folder where the compressed file should be saved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was because the SQL service agent was not granted write permission to the folder where the compressed file should be saved.

Comment: Thanks for returning with an answer